# How to use a custom field for search engine optimization

Tags: custom-field, search-engines

My posts (not custom) have a custom field - this has very important information.  Can I use this information to submit to search engines.  Note: This is something like a product site and has many posts.  I am looking for an automated way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugins [Relevanssi](http://www.relevanssi.com/) or [Search Everything](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/) and configure them to search custom fields.